# Playframework: Can I reference previously defined property in the messages file?

Tags: string, playframework, message

I'd like to do the following 
(only because  it is elegant to do it here than in Java/javascript code)

```
messages file
-------------
greeting=hello
message= ?greeting? world!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the play framework code (play.i18n.MessagesPlugin and play.i18n.Messages) this is not supported.